# Which tense should be used after "if" in these cases?

Tags: grammar

"Mom asks if you help her" and "Mom asks whether you help her"

I'm interested in which tense I should use after IF: future simple or just present simple?

So, perhaps the sentence "Mom asks if you'll help her" is correct.

Comment: If she is _requesting_ help, yes, it's 'asks if you will help her'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When **"whether"** or **"if"** introduces **an indirect question**, you can use the future tense when appropriate:

> Mom asks whether you will help her. [Mom asks : Will you help her?]

**"If"** is often used in the sense of "whether" :

> Mom asks if you will help her.